# How to make an express js temporary route/path for image?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have created an API with express to submit a user form with an image with multer. Now I want to make the URL of the image temporary for a certain amount of time so that no user can see the image after that particular time and one URL is fixed for one user only but if he wants to see it again he has to request a new URL.

```
https://localhost:3000/api/image?=sometempURL1
```

for another user, the same image should have another unique URL like

```
https://localhost:3000/api/image?=sometempURL2orSomething
```

just don't want to reveal the actual file path/name

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use routes with parameters: `/path/:id`
The `id` would be the path to the file hashed using a hashing method.

You would have 2 locations for the files, one temporary and one permanently. When you get a file, you store it in both locations. You can save the location to the permanent one. For you temporary route, you can return to use the hashed path of the file in temporary location.

Now how is this temporary location? You can use [Cronjob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to schedule it's deletion.

So you provide to the user `/path/to/file.jpg` under this format: `b017bcade5394d0076ad808e94482576` and the route would look like: `/file/b017bcade5394d0076ad808e94482576` and you can get the file using this hashed value, but at some point (depending on the time you set on cronjob) the file will be deleted from the temporary location, so the link will become invalid